# OutOfRangeException in StringBuilder.Remove()

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains a lot of useless information after the first char: space. So I built a StringBuilder to remove unnecesary characters after the first space.

```
public static string Remove(string text)
{
    int index1 = text.IndexOf(' ');
    int index2 = text.Lenght;
    StringBuilder sv = new StringBuilder(text.Lenght);
    sv.Append(text);
    sv.Remove(index1, index2);
    string text2 = sv.ToString();

    return text2;
}
```

Can somebody explain why this throws me an error? Thank you!

Comment: Exception is pretty clear. You are giving out-of-bounds index to Remove() function.

Comment: SB is significant overkill  here, basic string manipulation will suffice.

Comment: `IndexOf` can return -1

Comment: You are spelling `Length` wrong, so unless you wrote this code down on top of your head, I’d say that you are not actually running *this* code. Which makes it hard to guess what the error could be. Also, please post the actual error and stack trace and show where it appears.

Comment: Also adding the length of the string to any non-negative index will cause it to be larger than the string. And [`StringBuilder#Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) takes as second parameter the amount of characters it's supposed to remove, not a second index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this exception is that you misunderstood the purpose of the second parameter: rather than specifying the ending *index*, it specifies the *length* of the segment to be removed.

Since your code is passing the length of the entire `text` string, the only valid input for the first parameter would be zero. To pass a proper value, subtract the first index from the second index, and add 1 to the result.

**Note:** It looks like you are removing everything from the string starting at the first space `' '`. A simpler way of doing it would be with substring:

```
int index = text.IndexOf(' ');
return index >= 0 ? text.Substring(0, index) : text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) says it all - only one exception is raised for that method

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: If startIndex or length is less than zero, or startIndex + length is greater than the length of this instance.

So one of two things is going on

1. Your string does not contain a space (`startIndex` will be less than zero)
2. The `startIndex`+`length` is greater than the total length of the string.

Crucially, with the code you've posted 1. above could sometimes be true, and 2. will *always* be true! You should have done `index2-index1` for the second parameter.